# How to clone javafx.scene.image.Image?

Tags: javafx

Is it possible to clone `javafx.scene.image.Image`, not using pixel by pixel copying?
Or [this](http://java-buddy.blogspot.com/2012/12/javafx-example-copy-image-pixel-by.html) is the only way?

Comment: What do you want to do? Really clone the image or use the same image multiple times on your scene? Because in that case simply add the image to the ImageViews you create.

Comment: I need exactly to clone the image.

Answer (score 0):

The code below copied from your link and put into a separate function is definitely not the "only" solution to the problem. It is definitely the best work-around that i personally know of. So here is the code for cut&paste:

**copyImage**

```
   /**
     * copy the given image to a writeable image
     * @param image
     * @return a writeable image
     */
    public static WritableImage copyImage(Image image) {
      int height=(int)image.getHeight();
      int width=(int)image.getWidth();
      PixelReader pixelReader=image.getPixelReader();
      WritableImage writableImage = new WritableImage(width,height);
      PixelWriter pixelWriter = writableImage.getPixelWriter();

      for (int y = 0; y < height; y++){
          for (int x = 0; x < width; x++){
              Color color = pixelReader.getColor(x, y);
              pixelWriter.setColor(x, y, color);
          }
      }
      return writableImage;
    }
```

**Use in the context of an ImageView**

If you have an ImageView that might have a readonly image this is how you get a copy "on the fly".

Platform.runLater() might be needed when calling the setImage ...

```
/**
 * get the writeAbleImage (if available)
 * 
 * @return the writeAbleImage or null if the image is not writeAble
 */
public WritableImage getWriteableImage() {
  if (image instanceof WritableImage) {
    return (WritableImage) image;
  } else {
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO,"image is not writeable will create a writeable copy");
    WritableImage copyImage=copyImage(image);
    image=copyImage;
    imageView.setImage(image);
    return copyImage;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Late answer, you probably made it so far.

My solution to this topic is like that.

```
// First create a cache image
planTiles[1][1] = new PlanTile(1, 1, "");
ImageView cache = planTiles[1][1].renderImage();  // timeconsuming operation

// In loop, use cache: 
planTiles[iX][iY] = new PlanTile(iX, iY, "");
planTiles[iX][iY].setImage(cache.getImage());
```

Answer (score -3):

This is the solution:

```
writableImage = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(sourceImage, null), null)
```

Full code:

```
public class JavaFXApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    Image sourceImage = new Image("http://goo.gl/kYEQl");
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
    imageView.setImage(sourceImage);
    ImageView destImageView = new ImageView();

    //copying sourceImage
    destImageView.setImage(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(sourceImage, null), null));

    VBox vBox = new VBox();
    vBox.getChildren().addAll(imageView, destImageView);
    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(vBox);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 300);
    primaryStage.setTitle("java-buddy.blogspot.com");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Comment: These are just helper methods. You may as well create a helper method from the code in the link you provided. Besides, SwingFXUtils uses awt, so that's in fact not a good solution if you like to stick with pure JavaFX.

Comment: Why can't you use `destImageView.setImage(sourceImage)`?

Comment: Because I need another object, sir. Not just the reference to an old one.

Comment: I admit, SwingFXUtils is not good solution, But Oracle didnt do anything to provide something decent to clone at least JavaFx images. If I want to write short code I have to use an ugly way using SwingFXUtils, otherwise I gonna be forced to do my own implementation of nonexisting javafx.superCloneUtil.cloneImage(Image image) method, which certantly must exist.

Comment: Then just extend from Image, implement the Cloneable interface and add the 9 lines of code from the link you provided. Or create an ImageUtils class with a public static Image clone( Image sourceImage) {... 9 lines of code ...} method. If you clone them and can't re-use the images, you certainly have more image manipulation code to implement anyway.