# JavaFX: Periodically repainting an ImageView using the Service class. The image remains unchanged

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, worker

I have a problem with multithreading in JavaFX. I use the class `Service` from `javafx.concurrent` package to periodically recalculate and change the image in an `ImageView`.
To do this I have this method, which is called right from the JavaFX application's `start()` method:

```
public void startRepaintingThread() {
    for (GameWindow gamewindow : gameWindows) {
        RepaintingLoopService service = new RepaintingLoopService(gamewindow);
        service.setOnSucceeded((eh) -> {
            gamewindow.setImage(service.getValue());
            service.reset();
            service.start();
        });
        service.start();
    }
}
```

Here `GameWindow` is a simple subclass of `ImageView` and `RepaintingLoopService` is a subclass of `javafx.concurrent.Service` which does some complex logic to recalculate the image and returns the new image as its value. Now I verified using debugger and logging, that `service.getValue()` in this code actually DOES return the correctly recalculated image, so the recalculation logic is correct, but still in the UI the image remains unchanged! Or, to be more precise: In some very rare cases it actually changes, but in 95% of cases it remains a static image (the first one painted), so it seems to depend on some race condition or something … Well I thought, maybe you have some idea what might be wrong? I set the global variable `gameWindows` to `volatile`, as well as all other global variables used by multiple threads. Maybe I am using the `Service` the wrong way somehow?

**========= EDIT ====================**

I indeed could build a small complete example which reproduces the error. See the code below. The `Service` in this application does periodically repaint an image, starting off with a white image and each time adding a row of black pixels.
And again: It seems to work … sometimes: For me it worked fine the first time I ran it, but any of the following times I started the program, the image in the UI did not change anymore after the first 2 or 3 black lines were added … 
Here is the code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class BugFix extends Application {

    private static final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 800;
    private static final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 800;

    /**
     * Time in ms between repainting attempts
     **/
    private static final long REPAINTING_TIME = 100;

    private ImageView imageView;
    private RepaintingService service = new RepaintingService();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        setUpStage(primaryStage);
        startService();
    }

    private void setUpStage(Stage stage) {
        Group group = new Group();
        imageView = new ImageView(new WritableImage(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT));
        group.getChildren().add(imageView);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(group, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT));
        stage.show();
    }

    private void startService() {
        service.setOnSucceeded((eh) -> {
            imageView.setImage(service.getValue());
            int firstWhiteLine = findFirstWhiteLineInImage(service.getValue());
            System.out.println("First white line in received image: " + firstWhiteLine);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(REPAINTING_TIME);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            service.reset();
            service.start();
        });
        service.start();
    }

    /**
     * For debug purposes: Do find the number of the first line with white pixels
     * in the given image.
     **/
    private int findFirstWhiteLineInImage(Image repaintedImage) {
        for (int line = 0; line < repaintedImage.getHeight(); line++) {
            if (Color.WHITE.equals(repaintedImage.getPixelReader().getColor(0, line))) {
                return line;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    /**
     * A service to periodically repaint the image,
     * starting off with a white image and with each repainting adding a black line of pixels.
     **/
    private class RepaintingService extends Service<Image> {

        private volatile WritableImage image = new WritableImage(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        private int blackLinesCount = 0;

        @Override
        protected Task<Image> createTask() {
            return new Task<Image>() {

                @Override
                protected Image call() {
                    repaintImage();
                    blackLinesCount++;
                    return image;
                }
            };
        }

        /**
         * Repaints the image with the upper n lines being black
         * and the remaining lines being white.
         **/
        private void repaintImage() {
            for (int line = 0; line < WINDOW_HEIGHT; line++) {
                for (int column = 0; column < WINDOW_HEIGHT; column++) {
                    Color color = line <= blackLinesCount ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE;
                    image.getPixelWriter().setColor(column, line, color);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In any case, the console output of the program is always the same:

```
First white line in received image: 1
First white line in received image: 2
First white line in received image: 3
First white line in received image: 4
First white line in received image: 5
```

(and so on... ) So, again, this means, that the image, which is read from `service.getValue()` is always the correctly repainted image. But for some reason, it is not (always) shown in the UI, though exactly this image is passed to `imageView.setImage()` in the same line.

Comment: My guess is that the `RepaintingLoopService` objects are being garbage collected. Try keeping a strong reference to them.

Comment: @Slaw Thank you for your hint! I added a field repaintingService to the GameWindow class and now I am taking the service instances from there, but unfortunately the behavior remains the same :(

Comment: Can you show your `Service` and `Task` implementation (i.e. a [mre])?

Comment: I indeed managed to build a short but complete example which reproduces the same problem (see my edit).

Comment: it's always the same instance of image, so basically, you are updating a (property of a) view which is live in the scenegraph off the fx application thread - which you must not do, never ever.

Comment: Hmm .. when using a copy of the [repainted image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51919485/203657) the update looks like expected - could well be that doing so goes against why you put the repainting into a background thread :) Don't know much about image processing, so can't give any advice on copying effectively, but would see the mere fact that copying behaves correctly is an indication that you _must_ do it somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is that a property (here: the pixels in the image) of a node (imageView) that is active in the scenegraph is updated off the fx application thread. Which effectively blocks the update of the ui itself.

A solution is to let the background thread return a copy of the image it is working on:

```
// in your task

@Override
protected Task<Image> createTask() {
    return new Task<Image>() {

        @Override
        protected Image call() {
            repaintImage();
            blackLinesCount++;
            return copyImage(image);
        }
    };
}
```

A utility method - simply taken from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51919485/203657) just to demonstrate the effect:

```
/**
 * copy the given image to a writeable image
 * @param image
 * @return a writeable image
 */
public static WritableImage copyImage(Image image) {
    int height = (int) image.getHeight();
    int width = (int) image.getWidth();
    PixelReader pixelReader = image.getPixelReader();
    WritableImage writableImage = new WritableImage(width, height);
    PixelWriter pixelWriter = writableImage.getPixelWriter();

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            Color color = pixelReader.getColor(x, y);
            pixelWriter.setColor(x, y, color);
        }
    }
    return writableImage;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The solution with using a new image every time instance really solves the problem! I also will try to maybe somehow put the call to update the view into the application thread, maybe if there is a way to do it, this would be a more optimal solution. I don't really like the idea to create a new image every few milliseconds :) And again, thanks a lot for the explanation, I was fighting with this problem for some days now :)